# Why lists created with cons() and list() are shown differently?

Tags: list, lisp

Why lists created with cons() and list() are shown differently despite the lists are equal? The first one shows items separated by dot, but second one do w/o.

```
> (cons 1 2)
(1 . 2)

> '(1 2)
(1 2)
```

I know that `cons` constructs dotted pair, but in this case the lists are same but shown differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on Basile's answer:

```
(1 2)
```

is a *proper list* of length two. That is, it contains two cons cells:

```
#1=(1 . #2#)
#2=(2 . ())
```

On the other hand,

```
(1 . 2)
```

is an *improper list* of length one. That is, it contains one cons cell:

```
#1=(1 . 2)
```

A non-empty proper list is a list where the last cons cell's `cdr` that contains the empty list, `()`. A non-empty improper list is a list where the last cons cell's `cdr` contains anything else.

Answer (score 8):

It is **not the same list**; a list such as

```
  (1 2)
```

which is returned by your quoted (i.e. 2nd) expression is the same as the result of

```
 (cons 1 (cons 2 ())
```

A proper list like above is always a single-linked list of pairs whose last pair has a nil tail.

Answer (score 0):

Let me expand previous answers still further

Although we are talking about Lisp language here, I notice that a line from **Page 8 and 9** of a famous Book named ["The Little Schemer (4th edition)"](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/jaredmc/The_Little_Schemer_-_Daniel_P._Friedman_-_4th_Ed.pdf) help me understand the 2 puzzling facts altogether:

```
    Why is (cons 1    2) does not look like '(1 2)?
    Why is (cons 1 '(2)) does     look like '(1 2)?
    ----
    > (cons 1 2)
    (1 . 2)
    > (cons 1 '(2))
    (1 2)
    > '(1 2)
    (1 2)
```

> Just read the **"The Laws of Cons"**:
>
> The **primitive** *`cons`* takes 2 arguments.
>
> The 2nd argument to *`cons`* must be a list.
>
> The result is a list.
>
> **In practice:** (**cons** A B) works for ***all values A and B***, And
>
> > (**car** (**cons** A B)) = A
> >
> > (**cdr** (**cons** A B)) = B